# SIGABRT ABORT crash on iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I am getting a SIGABRT ABORT crash at the line mentioned below the comment(let data = fbResult.objectForKey("data") as! NSMutableArray). I am just trying to get user's score saved over Facebook. Please note that I am not able to reproduce this issue and this is happening on a very few devices. I just got the issue through crash reports.

```
var fbScore = 0
func getFBScore(){
    if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil){
        var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/scores?fields=score", parameters: nil)
        request.startWithCompletionHandler({(connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if(error != nil){
                println("facebook score reading failed with error \(error)")

            } else {
                println("facebook score reading result \(result)")
                let fbResult = result as! NSDictionary
                //crash on below line
                let data = fbResult.objectForKey("data") as! NSMutableArray
                if(data.count == 0){
                    self.postFBScore(0)
                } else {
                    if let mScore = data[0].objectForKey("score") as? Int{
                        self.fbScore = mScore
                        println("facebook score is \(self.fbScore)")
                    } else{
                        self.postFBScore(0)
                    }

                }
            }

        })
    }
}
```

This is the crash report I have got.

```
    Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
    0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001954db270 __pthread_kill + 8
    1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000195579160 pthread_kill + 112
    2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000195452aa0 abort + 112
    3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x0000000100a6dd80 swift::fatalError(char const*, ...) + 182
    4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x0000000100a4aefc swift::swift_dynamicCastFailure(void const*, char const*, void const*, char const*, char const*) + 70
    5  libswiftCore.dylib             0x0000000100a4af80 swift::swift_dynamicCastFailure(swift::Metadata const*, swift::Metadata const*, char const*) + 130
    6  libswiftCore.dylib             0x0000000100a6f6dc swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 72
    7  MY_APP                     0x00000001000e5c70 MY_APP.GameScene.(getFBScore (MY_APP.GameScene) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) (GameScene.swift:1600)
    8  MY_APP                     0x00000001003d6ea4 -[FBSDKGraphRequestMetadata invokeCompletionHandlerForConnection:withResults:error:] (FBSDKGraphRequestMetadata.m:48)
    9  MY_APP                     0x00000001003ddef0 __82-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:]_block_invoke394 (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:719)
    10 MY_APP                     0x00000001003ddca0 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:] (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:768)
    11 MY_APP                     0x00000001003dd768 __64-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection completeWithResults:networkError:]_block_invoke (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:697)
    12 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001832b0d48 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 132
    13 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001832b0c2c -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 312
    14 MY_APP                     0x00000001003dd500 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection completeWithResults:networkError:] (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:679)
    15 MY_APP                     0x00000001003dc950 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection completeFBSDKURLConnectionWithResponse:data:networkError:] (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:544)
    16 MY_APP                     0x00000001003da910 __36-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection start]_block_invoke_2 (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:188)
    17 MY_APP                     0x00000001003d76ec -[FBSDKURLConnection invokeHandler:error:response:responseData:] (FBSDKURLConnection.m:104)
    18 MY_APP                     0x00000001003d7644 -[FBSDKURLConnection logAndInvokeHandler:response:responseData:] (FBSDKURLConnection.m:96)
    19 MY_APP                     0x00000001003d7a28 -[FBSDKURLConnection connectionDidFinishLoading:] (FBSDKURLConnection.m:143)
    20 CFNetwork                      0x0000000182e391e8 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 80
    21 CFNetwork                      0x0000000182e39178 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 208
    22 CFNetwork                      0x0000000182e392f4 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 60
    23 CFNetwork                      0x0000000182d0bdfc ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 104
    24 CFNetwork                      0x0000000182dd6120 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 104
    25 CFNetwork                      0x0000000182cf7efc RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 76
    26 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018329c97c CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    27 CFNetwork                      0x0000000182cf7da8 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 136
    28 CFNetwork                      0x0000000182cf7c5c MultiplexerSource::perform() + 312
    29 CFNetwork                      0x0000000182cf7a88 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 68
    30 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183373f8c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    31 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183373230 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
    32 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001833712e0 __CFRunLoopRun + 712
    33 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018329cf74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
    34 GraphicsServices               0x000000018cba76fc GSEventRunModal + 168
    35 UIKit                          0x0000000187e9ed94 UIApplicationMain + 1488
    36 MY_APP                     0x00000001000f6c58 main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
    37 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001953c2a08 start + 4
```

When I try to print fbResult on my console this is what I get.

> {
>       data =     (
>                   {
>               score = 41;
>               user =             {
>                   id = 10206371034343540;
>                   name = "Rohit Goyal";
>               };
>           }
>       ); }

Comment: you are downcasting fbResult.objectForKey("data")  as NSMutableArray. 
If dictionary key is known to contain only NSMutableArray instances, you can downcast and unwrap directly to a non-optional NSMutableArray with the forced version of the type cast operator (as!):

could you print fbResult in console and share?

Comment: the `data` key is an array? Print the result console here or if it long use pastie.

Comment: @Prabhu.Somasundaram Here it is.  {
    data =     (
                {
            score = 41;
            user =             {
                id = 10206371034343540;
                name = "Rohit Goyal";
            };
        }
    );
}

Comment: @Prabhu.Somasundaram When I try the same thing over graph api tool explorer it gives me an array. And on iOS I am getting parentheses instead of brackets. Does this make any difference. Do note that it is working perfectly on my devices. Any ideas?

Comment: @iAshish please read my above comment and share your views as well.

Comment: Even I am facing same issue. The crash is only happening for few users.  Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is an exception at this line:

```
let data = fbResult.objectForKey("data") as! NSMutableArray
```

given the fact that the Swift is a strongly and static typed language, the only possible cause of error is the use of the `!` operator to cast the object to the type `NSMutableArray`. So, if you know that the value bound to the key `data` is an array, you should try to cast it to a non mutable array:

```
let data = fbResult.objectForKey("data") as! NSArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing it like this:

**Current**:

```
let data = fbResult.objectForKey("data") as! NSMutableArray
```

**New**:

```
let data = fbResult.objectForKey("data").mutablecopy() as! NSMutableArray
```